# How to set focus on login box that render when click on sub menu bar?

Tags: user-input, oracle-adf, submenu, setfocus

I have menu bar that consist on menu and login.Each of this menu has its own sub menu.When I click on the submenu, it will render panel group layout that contain input text for login such as username and password.My question is how to set focus on the username every time i click on submenu on menu bar?

Here I attach the structure of my menu and submenu.

```
MENU
   -Overview

LOGIN
   -Employee
   -Manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to set the focus when your page loads.
Or use google and find this : https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how_to_programmatically_set_focus